# What is the best practice for committing the `Dependencies.toml` in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

If the project does not contain the `Dependencies.toml` file, the build command can automatically regenerate it. Hence, do we need to commit the `Dependencies.toml`? and what is the best practice regarding maintaining the `Dependencies.toml`?

Answer (score 0):

It is best to always commit the `Dependencies.toml` file because if there is a major release from a dependency of your project, it can break your existing code due to incompatible changes. By default, Ballerina does not include the `Dependencies.toml` in the `.gitignore` file generated with a new project for this reason.